# How do you use fluxbox in OpenBSD

Tags: desktop-environment, openbsd, fluxbox, sparc

I recently installed OpenBSD on my sparc64 workstation and I wanted to use fluxbox for my desktop environment. When I install it and try to start it it gives a error saying "couldn't connect to xserver passing null display" I looked online an saw something about editing the .xsession file but it is not there I only have the root user because I didn't set up any other users but I did reinstall it once and added a user with but the file still wasn't there. I want to make fluxbox start automatically after logging in. I am very new to UNIX so please help.

Edit: I actually also wanted to try icewm but it gives the error "cant open display: . X must be running and $DISPLAY set."

Comment: how are you actually trying to start your preferred window manager? directly from the text console? as the error messages indicate, you must have X running (e.g. through `startx`) to run an X window manager

Comment: That’s what I’m asking how do I get it to start by typing startx

Comment: so if you run `startx` and try to start the window manager from the xterm window that appears, does it work?

Comment: also, if you're told to edit a specific file, and that file doesn't exist, that's a cue to _make_ that file. `.xinitrc` and `.xsession` aren't created automatically

Comment: Start `fluxbox` from your `.xsession` file, and make sure that `xenodm` is enabled with `rcctl enable xenodm` (as root) followed by `rcctl start xenodm` (also as root, or do a reboot). Does that solve it?  Don't start X or `fluxbox` from the console.

Comment: I added the .xsession file in the root directory and used part of the example here https://www.openbsdhandbook.com/x_window_system/ to start it but it didn't work it still went to cwm

Comment: A bit late reply, but _$HOME/.xinitrc_ and _$HOME/.xsession_ files are just shell scripts, with the added restriction that usually they pass control to the last command (a WM) with `exec`. That `exec` needs to be the very last command in that file. _.xinitrc_ is for **startx**,  _.xsession_ is for **xenodm**. **xenodm** is now the preferred way to start X on OpenBSD, as the alternative, **startx**, requires making the _Xorg_ executable setuid, which isn't recommended due to security reasons. So, set the last line in _$HOME/.xsession_ as `exec startfluxbox` and remove any other `exec` line,